# DataFrame can't be iterated through: getting following error: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning

I've been trying to debug my code for the last 30 minutes to no avail, maybe you can help?

The error lies withing line 17, but I'm truly clueless to why it's happening.

So, I'm using a dictionary in order to store the data that my function `is_nontrivial_reverse_number()` returns, which is a `boolean` type. I iterate through it and insert all of the values from `0` to `1100`.

I then insert my dictionary into a `DataFrame` with the `pandas` library.

Then I iterate through my dataFrame in order to retrieve the count of the values that are set to true.

But the problem is that `row["nonTrivial"]` doesn't seem to be working, even though I used the same function on a different dictionary and dataframe set.

```
import pandas as pd2

dic2 = {'nonTrivial': [is_nontrivial_reverse_number(x) for x in range(0, 1100)]}
dic2

df2 = pd2.DataFrame(dic2)
df2 = df2.set_index('nonTrivial')

#df2.head()
##df2.shape
#df.dtypes



for row in df2.iterrows():
    if (row["nonTrivial"]==True):
        n = n+1
print (n)
```

Expected result : `n=2`

### what I get:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-314-ce7c400929e6> in <module>
     15
     16 for row in df2.iterrows():
---> 17     if (row["nonTrivial"]==True):
     18         n = n+1
     19 print (n)

TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Comment: iterrows returns a tuple. Change `for row in df2.iterrows()` to `for idx, row in df2.iterrows()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`iterrow` returns a `tuple`. If you need to access the index of the column you want, you can do it with:

```
for row in df2.iterrows():
    if (row[1][df.columns.get_loc('nonTrivial') == True):
        n = n+1
```

Just a comment, you don't need to loop the rows. You can just do:

```
n += (df2['nonTrivial']==True).sum()
```

Comment: +1 for advising OP not to use loops. Not much of a pandas user myself but heard on multiple occasions to avoid loops.

Comment: Thank you so much for the advice, I'll avoid using loops from now on. though sadly this didn't fix my bug, even though it worked like a charm on my first dictionary.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your help sir! now my code works like a charm, and again thank you for your tip, I'll make good use of it

Comment: @hqkhan Sometimes loops are needed, especially when you need to maintain state between iterations. Avoiding loops is not always possible. Better to get your code to work first, then figure out if loops can be avoided: #poitroae

Answer (score 10):

Why noone mentioned that he can unpack the tuple in the for loop like

```
for index, row in df2.iterrows():
    if (row["nonTrivial"]==True):
        n = n+1
    print (n)
```

Comment: That's the simplest solution! Thank you .

Comment: This should be the accepted solution! Btw you could just do `for _, row` since you are not using the index

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
for row in df2.iterrows():
   if (row[1]["nonTrivial"]==True):
         n = n+1
```